# Jetty doesn't send .ts files from server in my typescript with java EE project

Tags: javascript, java, maven, typescript, jetty

I have built a simple services framework for java [to be opensourced soon].

I have a demo client built with typescript that compiles and runs fine. The project is configure to use jetty maven plugin with the following configuration -

```
<!-- jetty configuration -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
    <configuration>
        <webapp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webapp>
        <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</webAppSourceDirectory>
        <stopWait>10</stopWait>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8080</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
        </connectors>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.29</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <!-- <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog"> 
            <filename>./target/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename> <retainDays>90</retainDays> 
            <append>true</append> <extended>false</extended> <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone> 
            </requestLog> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the problem is that when the client is running jetty doesn't seem to deliver the typescript files for the javascript generated though my source map configuration seems accurate i.e. it generates the source maps properly and on the client it shows the typescript file names. But I see only empty files.

After some research it seems to be a jetty configuration issue i.e. it doesn't deliver the typescript files.

Any clues please ?

Comment: That configuration is very wrong.  Its a mix of Jetty 8 (the `SelectChannelConnector`), Jetty 9, and old versions of logback.  What are you trying to do?  Also, what is the expected mime-type for typescript files? (as it seems you'll need to configure that)

Comment: Can you please point me to a valid config for jetty 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Joakim Erdfelt comment I rectified the plugin configuration and removed the Connector part. Since Jetty 9 this connector can be optionally configured in Jetty.xml rather then in the plugin.

Using the defaults like this  -

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.v20161208</version>
            <configuration>
                <webapp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webapp>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.29</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

solves the issue of typescript files not being served. I still haven't figured the correct version of logback and will update this answer once I do.

Also found this Mycong example that drives the point home for reference on jetty 9 configuration-

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-jetty-plugin-examples/